# autocomplete freezes with up and down keys

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have used primeng autocomplete and it is working fine. but with arrow up and down keys, after 3-4 hits it gets freezes and not able to move down or up. with mouse scroll, it is working smoothly. I have only 100 of records in the autocomplete.

I tried with 10 elements in the filter and call the next 10 with scroll event. In this case, also I am facing the same problem.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example? planker or similar.